# Persist formatting of original document with JsonDocument

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, system.text.json

**Environment** .net 6 minimal api

```
app.MapPost("/HandleStatusUpdate", async (System.Text.Json.JsonDocument jsonBody, [FromServices] IMediator mediator, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) =>
```

I'm accepting webhook requests from a variety of sources and need to validate the message against a static key (static key + message = request header sha value) that I have from each service sending the request.

The issue I am having is that, when I convert the JsonDocument to string:

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream);
            jdoc.WriteTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

it's not re-creating the exact message that was sent (it removes spaces) so the verification step is failing.  I've verified that if I take the original message sent and run it through the verification step that it DOES validate.

It is a JSON string being sent with content type of application/json.  Since, I am accepting things from a variety of sources, I cant create a class that I can Serialize to.

I don't think there's a way I can tell the JsonDocument to persist the formatting of the Json document coming in, so is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `JsonDocument.RootElement.GetRawText()` to get the original JSON with the original formatting.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getrawtext?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-getrawtext):

> **JsonElement.GetRawText Method**
>
> Gets a string that represents the original input data backing this value.

Thus, you may just do:

```
return jdoc.RootElement.GetRawText();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fXl42F).